# Detect when a child CButton control is added to CDialog using WM_PARENTNOTIFY

Tags: c++, button, mfc, modal-dialog, message

Working with:

- Visual Studio 2017;
- MFC, C++.

I'm trying to modify a MFC project, for a `CDialog` derived class to detect when a child control is added to it ( `CButton` derived classes ). Preferably getting a handle (`HWND`) to those CButtons to process them further, like I can get from the parent dialog window with the following code:

> ```
> HWND handleParent = ::GetTopWindow(this->GetSafeHwnd());
> ```

I've read one way to do it, by handling `WM_PARENTNOTIFY`, but I cannot trigger it by any way using main event function: ***OnParentNotify*** (or `WindowProc` from some sources).

I've done the following, at least for `OnParentNotify`:

1. added a message export:

> ON_WM_PARENTNOTIFY()

2. in member function `DerivedDialog::OnInitDialog()` removed `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` style from all control handles possible, after `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` line of code:

> ```
> CDialog::OnInitDialog();
>
> HWND hwnd = ::GetTopWindow(this->GetSafeHwnd());
> while (hwnd)
> {
>     LONG lExStyle;
>     lExStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
>
>     if (lExStyle & WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY)
>     {
>         lExStyle &= ~WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY;
>         SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle);
>     }
>
>     hwnd = ::GetNextWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
> }
> ```

3. declared and defined function just to see if it is called:

> ```
> OnParentNotify(UINT message, LPARAM lParam)
> {
>
> CDialog::OnParentNotify(message, lParam)
> {
>     switch (LOWORD(message))
>     {
>         case WM_CREATE:
>         {
>             int a = 3;
>             int b = 2;
>         }
>         break;
>         case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
>         {
>             int c = 1;
>             int d = 0;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Unfortunately, only `WM_CREATE` is called once (don't think it is related or correct, since I have 2 buttons that must be added to dialog..so I expect 2 WM_CREATES if it is the case ??).

I am really not sure how to trigger that message to be called. Any tip would be very helpful !

Comment: If your control is handled by  a derived class, then you can override its `OnCreate(CREATESTRUCT *pCreateStruct)` member and send a message (that you have defined) to the dialog from there. Or just do what you need to in that overridden function. The `WM_CREATE` message for the new control will go to that control's handler.

Comment: Or, if you have the `WS_EX_PARENTNOTIFY` style ***set*** for your control, it will send `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` to the dialog on creation and destruction (test `wParam` to find out which).

Comment: I will try and test out the `WS_EX_PARENTNOTIFY` alternative, and let you know if I have any results. I gather that `wparam` is from another related function, like `OnParentNotify(...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations):

> The system also sends WM_PARENTNOTIFY messages when it creates and
>   destroys a window, but not for controls created from a dialog box
>   template. The system prevents these messages by specifying the
>   WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY style when creating the controls. An application
>   cannot override this default behavior unless it creates its own
>   controls for the dialog box.

According to this, all buttons that are created from dialog template will not receive `WM_PARENTNOTIFY`. (your code in `DerivedDialog::OnInitDialog()` has no affect).

The `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` works if you dynamically create a button (or child control).

Sample (add to your existing code):

1. Add `CButton m_sampleButton` member in the dialog header.
2. Add the creation to `OnInitDialog` code

   ```
   m_sampleButton.Create(L"Sample", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, CRect(10, 10, 100, 100), this, 10);
   ```

**Edit:** (inspired by @Adrian comment)

An alternative solution could be overriding the `PreSubclassWindow` function of your button's derived class and posting a user-defined message to the parent window.

**Button class:**

```
#define CUSTOM_CREATE_NOTIFY WM_USER+1001 // (add to header file)

void CCustomButton::PreSubclassWindow()
{   
    CButton::PreSubclassWindow();

    GetParent()->PostMessage(CUSTOM_CREATE_NOTIFY, (WPARAM)m_hWnd);
}
```

**Dialog class:**

```
// add to message map
ON_MESSAGE(CUSTOM_CREATE_NOTIFY, OnCustomNotify)

LRESULT CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnCustomNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM)
{   
    // wparam is the HWND to the button.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello EyIM ! So, from my understanding, dialog box template is basically what I have in my resource files (.rc files) as "descriptors" to the buttons I use in an end-user application ? Also to mention I exchange these buttons with the following ? :  `void CTestTipDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   DerivedDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON1, m_button);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON2, m_bitmapButton);
}`

Comment: Correct. These buttons are created automatically once the dialog is created.

Comment: Now this would be troublesome, then. I will try out Adrian's proposal above and post a working code if successful nevertheless. Thanks !

Comment: @Adrian and EyIM thank you very much for your tips. Indeed, I confirm what EyIM proposed that it is working (nice that you can create a custom message to send). This solution is, at the moment, a nice workaround and I will consider it a viable response.